# Thrust Reduce with binary_function and multiple types

Tags: cuda, thrust

How do you use thrust reduce with binary_functions with multiple types? In my case I have a struct FaceUV which has a member 'distance'. I want to count all of the FaceUV's with a distance != 0. How do I do this?

I thought it was this, but it does not compile:

```
struct FaceHasUVCmp : public thrust::binary_function<FaceUV, uint32_t, uint32_t> {
    __device__
        uint32_t operator()(const FaceUV& o1, const uint32_t& count) const {
        return count + (o1.distance != 0);
    }
};

float get_percent_of_FACES_with_UVs(thrust::device_ptr<FaceUV> face_uvs, unsigned int size){


    uint32_t num_with_UVs = thrust::reduce(thrust::cuda::par, face_uvs, face_uvs + size, 0, FaceHasUVCmp());

    return num_with_UVs / (float)size;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears this is similar to this question:

[Thrust reduce not working with non equal input/output types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540038/thrust-reduce-not-working-with-non-equal-input-output-types?rq=1)

"As talonmies notes, your reduction does not compile because thrust::reduce expects the binary operator's argument types to match its result type"

So it is not possible with thrust::Reduce. I still havent figures out how to accomplish what I want to do.

edit: I may need to use thrust::transform_reduce instead, but I cant figure out how to use that either.

Comment: it would, in fact, be possible with `thrust::reduce`, but you would need to implement a custom iterator for your type, rather than with a custom binary function